# Printing Results from Loops

Tags: python-2.7, loops

I currently have a piece of code that works in two segments. The first segment opens the existing text file from a specific path on my local drive and then arranges, based on certain indices, into a list of sub list. In the second segment I take the sub-lists I have created and group them on a similar index to simplify them (starts at def merge_subs). I am getting no error code but I am not receiving a result when I try to print the variable answer. Am I not correctly looping the original list of sub-lists? Ultimately I would like to have a variable that contains the final product from these loops so that I may write the contents of it to a new text file. Here is the code I am working with:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from operator import itemgetter
with open ("somepathname") as g:
    # reads text from lines and turns them into a list sub-lists
    lines = g.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        matrix = line.split()
        JD = matrix [2]
        minTime= matrix [5]
        maxTime= matrix [7]
        newLists = [JD,minTime,maxTime]
        L = newLists

def merge_subs(L):
    dates = {}
    for sub in L:
        date = sub[0]
        if date not in dates:
            dates[date] = []
        dates[date].extend(sub[1:])
    answer = []
    for date in sorted(dates):
        answer.append([date] + dates[date])
```

---

### new code

```
def openfile(self):
    filename = askopenfilename(parent=root)
    self.lines = open(filename)




def simplify(self):
    g = self.lines.readlines()
    for line in g:
        matrix = line.split()
        JD = matrix[2]
        minTime = matrix[5]
        maxTime = matrix[7]
        self.newLists = [JD, minTime, maxTime]
        print(self.newLists)
    dates = {}
    for sub in self.newLists:
        date = sub[0]
    if date not in dates:
        dates[date] = []
        dates[date].extend(sub[1:])
    answer = []

    for date in sorted(dates):
        print(answer.append([date] + dates[date]))

enter code here
```

enter code here

Comment: How are you calling `merge_subs`, and how & where do you try to print `answer`?

Comment: `L = newLists` don't you want to append newLists to L?

Comment: Try loading your project into Eclipse using PyDev plugin. I believe it has a debugger for python as well. Step through your code. It will show what it is really doing. It is also a good learning tool. I am not a big fan of Eclipse, but PyDev is very good and what I use for Python. And it's free.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am currently using PyCharm which connects to the pydev debugger and there are currently no issues with debugging since I receive and exit code of 0

Comment: I guess I am confused on the second part regarding the merge_subs function. Does it need to be created earlier in the text? I am new to python so I am probably missing a lot from my code. Ideally I would like the function merge_subs to work on the results from the variable L = newLists.

Comment: Here is another version using functions. I'm not sure if the final list of lists that I am trying to obtain is possible. Can you pass the results of one function to another with the data structure I am trying to work with?

Comment: Just a general advice : when the output after a whole bunch of code is not what was expected, you have to test smaller elements, or at least display traces of what happens or what are the values of key variables all along the processing.

Comment: Understood. I have a section of the code posted that I is proving to be the most difficult. I've narrowed the scope of my issue down to the simplify function. It opens the self.lines member of the class and takes certain indices and creates the another member/variable called self.newLists. The next loop is what is confusing and seems to compile but produce no results when printed. My main concern is that self.newLists actually doesn't have anything for the next loop to work with. Is this correct?